# Creating a method in Java

Tags: java

How do a put the contents of case 1 into a method and call it?

See code snippet below:

```
 Teacher jane = new Teacher("jane");
 Teacher alex = new Teacher("alex");

 Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<Teacher>();
 teachers.add(jane);
 teachers.add(alex);

 int selection = scan.nextInt();
 switch (selection) {
     case 1:
         for (Teacher teacher : teachers) {
             System.out.printf("%s ", teacher.getName());
         }
         break;
 }
```

Comment: See [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: Use your `"IDE->Refactor->Extract Method"`

Comment: By the way, I recommend you a book on the subject by Martin Fowler and Kent Beck - "Refactoring: improving the design of existing code".

Comment: @GETah, you really think he's using a full blown IDE if he can't do this by hand? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaration:

```
void printNames(Iterable<Teacher> teachers) {
    for (Teacher teacher : teachers) {
        System.out.printf("%s ", teacher.getName());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
switch (selection) {
     case 1:
         printNames(teachers);
         break;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private void showNames(Set<Teacher> teachers) {
    for (Teacher teacher : teachers) {
        System.out.printf("%s ", teacher.getName());
    }
}
```

Invoke with:

```
showNames(teachers);
```

Note that the `break` is not tucked into the function. The function wouldn't have access to the scope of the `case` statement, and therefore `break` would do nothing. Make sure `break` follows your function invocation.

One other thing to point out is the type that I used on the function. I used a `Set`. Matt Ball used an `Iterable`. I'm going to leave mine in for the sake of comparison, but using an `Iterable` is best! The reason is that all Collection types implement the `Iterable` interface. Inside the function, we are merely iterating over the Set. Therefore, the more general `Iterable` is the best type choice for the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The method:

```
public void printTeachers(set<Teacher> teachers){
  for (Teacher teacher : teachers) {
    System.out.printf("%s ", teacher.getName());
  }
}
```

The other code:

```
Teacher jane = new Teacher("jane");
Teacher alex = new Teacher("alex");

Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<Teacher>();
teachers.add(jane);
teachers.add(alex);

int selection = scan.nextInt();
switch (selection) {
    case 1:
        printTeachers(teachers);
        break;
```