# What is missing in this code block?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Application development and so I am learning from this site and from any other website I get to pass through!

From another site I got the code to show the current DateTime value of the phone. The code is as:

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
SimpleDateFormat timeNow = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
textView1.setText(timeNow.format(new Date()));
```

Now, I used this site to get the refreshing suggestion for each second, so I will use a Timer.

The code now, looks like this:

```
private static updateTextView () {
   TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   SimpleDateFormat timeNow = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
   textView1.setText(timeNow.format(new Date()));
}

private Timer timer1 = new Timer();
timer1.schedule(updateTextView, 1000);
```

I am doing this on my own, each timer needs its own method, so I tried to create one. But since I am a newbie I don't know how to create a method in Java. And the error is at `static` the error line is:

> insert enumbody to complete block statement

What would I do now?

---

The complete code is as:

```
package com.something.widget;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main_Page extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
        private static TextView updateTextView () {
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        SimpleDateFormat timeNow = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        textView1.setText(timeNow.format(new Date()));
        }

        private Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(updateTextView, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main__page, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably don't need to make your method static if you are first creating an object then calling the method. Are you familiar with what `static` is/does?

Comment: NO @csmckelvey I am sorry, but I am just a first day student for Java. Until now I used ASP.NET language for development..But hey, I never used C# even..I used ASP.NET Razor view engine..

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a method in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375916/creating-a-method-in-java)

Comment: Please post your complete code, the error is not in what you posted, but somewhere else in the syntax.

Comment: @C.Ross I have included complete code now :) .. its just a starter app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a method nested inside another method body, it needs to be declared in the class body, just like in C#.  It also should not be `static`, so it has access to the `findViewById` method, and `void` because it does not return anything.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //...
 }

 private void updateTextView () {
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    SimpleDateFormat timeNow = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    textView1.setText(timeNow.format(new Date()));
 }
```

Also the `Timer` should be a class level object, and its schedule method takes a [`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html).  You can create a new [anonymous timer task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) with this syntax.

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
     void run() {
       //Your code ...
     }
}
```

But in general perhaps you should read up on Java a bit before attempting this. I suggest the [Oracle Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html).

Comment: When I tried this, there were some errors. Now I am going through this one, can you tell me why this method is not ending up there and wants me to keep the function open..http://s30.postimg.org/9zmhstgch/Screenshot_33.png ??

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan You need to learn the Java syntax, and back and forth in a StackOverflow question is not a good mechanism for that.  Please read up and do some tutorials.

Comment: I think your problem is actually on the line below where Eclipse is reporting it.  You seem to have some code that isn't actually inside any method.  As a general principle though, you shouldn't "accept" an answer until you've managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

To use a `Timer`, you need to create a `TimerTask` object, whose `run()` method runs the code that you need.  You could write it like this (although this is not the only way).

```
// To create the timer -

Timer timer1 = new Timer();
timer1.schedule(new TextViewTask(), 1000);

// In TextViewTask.java - package declaration and imports omitted

public class TextViewTask.java extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        SimpleDateFormat timeNow = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        textView1.setText(timeNow.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```